# When a listener is removed, is it okay that the event be called on that listener one more time?

Tags: java, listener

Most people use a ConcurrentLinkedQueue or CopyOnWriteArrayList to collect listeners and notify them when something happens. The drawback of that is that it is possible that a listener can get a notification while it already unregistered himself. This happens if the manager (collection, ..., give it a name) is iterating over the collection of listeners and some listener unregisters himself during that iteration.

So, the 'remove listener' contract is broken. Would you consider that as a problem?

Comment: The contract isn't broken necessarily.  It's just that the listener will receive one more event after it has been removed.

Comment: Correction: The listener *might* receive one more event after is has been removed.  This could only happen if the listener is unlucky enough to be removed while the list of listeners is being iterated over.

Comment: If the listener unregistered itself during that iteration how can it receive another event? Unless there is *another* iteration over the unmodified collection?

Comment: @EJP To answer your questions: "It can't" and "yes". (btw: here is the original question that the OP asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8259479/should-i-synchronize-listener-notifications-or-not/8259607)

Comment: @EJP If the listener is #8 and it deregisters itself while an event is being fired and in the process of notifying #3, then it will get one more event notification.

Comment: @Erick Robertson That would be listener #3 deregistering listener #8, not listener #8 deregistering itself.

Comment: @EJP No, I said what I meant.  In a multi-threaded system, listener #8 could deregister itself while an event is being fired.  In this case, listener #8 could be in a list of listeners currently being notified (but not yet notified) at the time it deregisters itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even if you checked the listener was still registered, in a multithreaded environment you still couldn't be sure it was still registered by the time you call it. Even for non-multithreaded situations, the standard implementation is to work on a copy.

Comment: So it's up to the listener implementation to filter late-coming events?

Comment: @JaperD Since nobody else can.. yes.

Comment: Yes, if it will be an issue for the listener implementation.